# OpenCV Connected Component labeling colours?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

this is displaying the correct result but it is colouring the objects with grey colour and its shades, i want them to be in different colours instead of shades of grey, like red, blue, green, pink, yellow etc.. How shall I do that? Plus, I would like to know, if it is possible to also see the image's matrix like in 0s, 1s form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to draw the contours on the same black&white image. You should make a different image like this:

```
image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img_bw->width, img_bw->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
```

This will be a 3 channel image and you will be able to draw BGR colors.

If you wanna see the intensity matrix representing all the pixels in the b&w image you can just output them in a text file or something.You can access any element like this:

```
unsigned char* dataRow = (unsigned char*)img_bw->imageData + i * img_bw->width;
unsigned char value = dataRow[j];
```